# Спрятать полосу прокрутки

Tags: html, css

Как можно спрятать полосу прокрутки, но в то же время иметь возможность скроллить блок? Нужно реализовать что-то похожее на прокрутку диалогов в соцсетях. Я так понимаю, **overflow** здесь не поможет

Если реально, то только css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать такой фокус с `overflow:hidden` и `overflow:auto`

Работает во всех браузерах

```css
*{margin:0;}
#container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: даже в ie11 работает

Comment: @MaximLensky  там же ничего  нету стандартный `overflow` :)

Comment: это конечно жесть но вот бы ещё на всю высоту -- наверно как то надо извратится

Comment: @MaximLensky сделал на всю высоту.

Comment: Мне тоже вариант понравился, только пока внедрить не получается))

Comment: я не могу два раза плюсануть !!

Comment: Всё получилось, всем спасибо :)

Comment: Есть 2 косяка: 1. Должно быть 17px, а не 15px - а то кусок скролла видно. 2. Паллинг рельно занимает место - если написать `text-align: justify`, то виден зазор между текстом и правым краем: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB9TI.png

Comment: @Qwertiy красавчик проста изменил мой ответ добавил 2 пикселя и вуаля .Хотя бы в ответе укажи что это доработанная версия моего ответа.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, это не доработанная версия. Я свою версию уже больше года использую. И вообще она другая. У тебя есть `overflow: scroll`? У тебя есть `margin`? Твоё решение будет работать при `box-sizing: border-box`? Так с чего же ты утверждаешь, что они одинаковые?

Comment: @Qwertiy отличные у тебя аргументы красавчик.Я не буду спорить ибо оба мы знаем что твой ответ копия.Иначе бы первым бы ответил ты а не я.А я бы проста прошел мимо поставив плюс.Удачи тебе.

Comment: Ага, отличный аргумент - я же робот, ежесекундно отслеживающий новые вопросы на SO, и постящий на них ответы до того, как это сделает кто-то ещё.

Answer (score 4):

В хроме можно селектором `::-webkit-scrollbar`

В мозилле - свойством `scrollbar-width: none;`

```css
.no-scrollbar {
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none; /*mozilla*/
}

.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; /*chrome*/
}
```

```html
<div class="no-scrollbar">
  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit
</div>
```

Comment: А кросс-браузерный вариант есть? Или хотя бы все, кроме IE :)

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко нашел в инете и добавил мозиллу, а потом уже и Максим подоспел =)

Comment: Я так понимаю, лучше всё-таки не ограничиваться css?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко тебя смутил jQuery ?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко смотря что нужно

Comment: @MaximLensky, я использую React и не знаю пока как туда внедрить JQ)

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко добавил вариант в сниппет

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, но ведь как раз FF не умеет стилизовать скроллбары...

Comment: @Qwertiy спрятать однако сумел, я проверил на какой-то версии :)

Comment: Прикольно, FF64+ - довольно новая штука. И всего 3 значения - почти никакой кастомизации...

Answer (score 3):

Я раньше отвечал уже на такой вопрос и по этому пример уже готовый

> jQuery в этом случае отвечает за синхронизацию прокрутки

```js
syncScroll($('.item1'), $('.item2'));

function syncScroll(el1, el2) {
  var $el1 = $(el1);
  var $el2 = $(el2);
  var forcedScroll = false;

  $el1.scroll(function() {
    performScroll($el1, $el2);
  });
  $el2.scroll(function() {
    performScroll($el2, $el1);
  });

  function performScroll($scrolled, $toScroll) {
    if (forcedScroll) return (forcedScroll = false);
    var percent = ($scrolled.scrollTop() /
      ($scrolled[0].scrollHeight - $scrolled.outerHeight())) * 100;
    setScrollTopFromPercent($toScroll, percent);
  }


  function setScrollTopFromPercent($el, percent) {
    var scrollTopPos = (percent / 100) *
      ($el[0].scrollHeight - $el.outerHeight());
    forcedScroll = true;
    $el.scrollTop(scrollTopPos);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items,
.items:after,
.items:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

span.title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  ;
}

.item1 {
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.item1 p {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  float: right;
}

.item-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-div div {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 30vw;
}

.item2 i.fa {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item2 h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.item2 span {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.item1,
.item2 {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.item1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

.item2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="items">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="customScroll1">
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title one</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title two</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-television"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title tree</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title four</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
        <span class="title">Headeing title fife</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
        <span class="title">Headeing title six</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="item2">
    <div class="customScroll2">


      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title one</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title two</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-television"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title tree</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title four</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title fife</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title six</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->


    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вариант без синхронизации

```css
html,
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

html,
body-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
.item{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet omnis repudiandae exercitationem, fugit est eligendi placeat quas, dolores repellat, deleniti officia similique dolorem! Vero temporibus molestias excepturi saepe fugit neque ipsam
cum est quam tenetur, error aspernatur id soluta labore ullam, eaque dolorem quibusdam facilis officia veniam, perspiciatis amet quae laudantium impedit! A suscipit commodi totam saepe perferendis quae libero rem ut placeat, aliquam eveniet non nostrum
laboriosam neque consequatur, iusto dolorem reiciendis quisquam itaque vel! At dicta excepturi alias non odit, maiores cupiditate voluptates repellat vitae. Numquam, laboriosam amet, atque, harum omnis repudiandae consectetur dicta optio beatae id architecto!
Necessitatibus veniam sint similique dignissimos officia aperiam odio culpa corporis nemo! Optio voluptatem officiis error quasi nostrum eligendi magni adipisci fugit, odit, quibusdam necessitatibus beatae, itaque laboriosam iste perferendis. Fuga sed
explicabo commodi perspiciatis consequuntur dolorem deserunt animi cupiditate ratione maxime facere fugiat veritatis libero, eum doloremque! Nisi repellendus assumenda nam ullam culpa magnam veritatis! Laborum consectetur facilis enim quisquam iusto corporis
repellat earum aspernatur excepturi modi repellendus doloremque deserunt, eum quam ab tenetur itaque atque! Hic quis rem numquam minima impedit officia quaerat excepturi! Ad sapiente qui officiis obcaecati deleniti fuga facere doloribus voluptatem quisquam
nam porro libero excepturi dicta, ratione a! In saepe earum corporis aperiam et omnis est, aliquam voluptas rem ea facilis placeat asperiores, facere porro debitis hic ipsa consequuntur eos. Perspiciatis et facilis voluptatem porro est deleniti ducimus
velit ipsam! Omnis ut officiis provident autem molestias nihil officia natus consectetur repudiandae labore quisquam, est quas maxime quaerat ex eum eos modi deserunt veritatis nesciunt harum, beatae perferendis. Deleniti fuga labore hic maiores soluta
nisi explicabo nostrum corporis. Dolore reprehenderit voluptates ab tempore repellendus iusto voluptatum et voluptate, expedita doloribus molestiae deserunt, consectetur similique at magni non. Vero illo magnam laborum earum quaerat deleniti alias temporibus
est fugit, tempore consequatur, quibusdam nemo nulla aliquid consequuntur! Numquam nam aspernatur magnam mollitia iusto officia ex. Numquam ducimus voluptas laboriosam, molestiae voluptates tenetur officia odit accusantium cum similique ut deserunt sunt
eaque quam magnam dolorum, praesentium explicabo accusamus nostrum facere iusto? Ex, dignissimos quia voluptas doloremque enim cumque facilis harum voluptatibus expedita dolore vel a nihil! Quia laboriosam tempora, modi doloribus a illo esse quod vero
quam rerum facilis possimus aliquid cum iste quo ab quaerat magni nulla mollitia, molestias excepturi aspernatur. Commodi, eaque ad sit cupiditate laborum culpa, adipisci natus esse explicabo totam distinctio quam quibusdam delectus corrupti ullam iste
tenetur in. Repellat ratione vero suscipit eligendi placeat, a iste earum ea facilis sunt! Illo qui iste nostrum sapiente labore unde ut quia eius temporibus, quaerat dolorem praesentium enim eos ad eligendi quod cumque. Necessitatibus quae officia accusantium
repellendus iure minima soluta similique eius. Doloremque autem minus, corrupti perspiciatis tempora reprehenderit quasi itaque repellendus culpa ab deleniti animi voluptatem. Autem cum quasi tempore, impedit minus quas commodi maiores ut. Minus atque
magnam qui a animi exercitationem beatae repellat culpa amet sed blanditiis, nostrum cum porro recusandae similique eaque corrupti laboriosam deserunt officiis excepturi voluptatum. Nulla molestias eius porro sit quis non quod deserunt excepturi esse
nihil debitis, sed deleniti adipisci facere. Autem optio aliquid laboriosam ad officiis in similique doloremque iure quisquam, ipsum laborum quidem recusandae unde deserunt doloribus error ea quam earum temporibus dicta iusto rerum fugiat dolores. Impedit,
nesciunt quae. Vel at aspernatur labore laboriosam? Vitae asperiores aliquam deserunt odit tempora, eligendi inventore fugit facere enim dolores animi maxime ipsam repellat excepturi adipisci mollitia. Ea odit architecto, totam repudiandae cupiditate
explicabo dolores dolore eligendi modi, natus expedita suscipit possimus ipsum. A eum sunt, amet soluta unde dolorem iure, eius sit totam enim, ad animi vel dignissimos nulla velit. Voluptate quibusdam accusamus excepturi earum, ut, reiciendis esse illo
repellat exercitationem quos culpa eveniet cumque nostrum enim unde necessitatibus ab. Nihil excepturi alias repudiandae voluptatum fugiat numquam obcaecati dicta velit culpa, impedit voluptate explicabo eum cupiditate laborum earum vero odio eaque dolore
debitis consequatur? Dolorem delectus maxime aut accusamus dicta distinctio officiis, cum asperiores non porro doloribus! Ipsa reprehenderit placeat rem ratione sint eaque voluptatibus ipsum? Tempore quas error officia eligendi itaque ipsa nihil provident
est recusandae, odit voluptatem, illo tenetur laudantium eius cupiditate ullam excepturi iure! Exercitationem expedita, tempore placeat aspernatur incidunt recusandae aliquid delectus molestias consequatur autem debitis in ad deserunt nesciunt commodi
ex tenetur consectetur nulla veniam blanditiis. Nihil, accusamus consequatur. Dolorem ea ad quia reprehenderit. Voluptates aut deleniti ullam nesciunt soluta exercitationem quas quaerat atque, a voluptatem nulla repellat alias totam explicabo qui sint
dolor vel cum pariatur repellendus vero dicta? Qui nobis voluptatum libero cupiditate distinctio magni magnam cumque perferendis aut dolor, nemo incidunt consequuntur nostrum sapiente quasi hic eius commodi mollitia! Soluta obcaecati, blanditiis, temporibus
i Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium adipisci culpa deleniti animi quos corrupti, vitae soluta, debitis exercitationem, quibusdam in temporibus sequi repellat. Aliquid reprehenderit voluptates omnis deleniti. Necessitatibus
aut labore blanditiis quidem. Quia magni culpa est doloremque velit consequatur molestias tempora aliquid ab aperiam, totam doloribus in esse non ducimus debitis aut sit minima quasi? Commodi laudantium error debitis illo, autem optio ea similique atque
delectus ullam eos ut! Sapiente itaque nesciunt dolore reiciendis fugiat modi perferendis earum reprehenderit facere? Quaerat quod, pariatur culpa quos tempore unde id accusamus repellat libero facilis maxime, architecto modi dicta eligendi nisi aut ullam
tenetur nulla! Rem minus pariatur saepe quia voluptatibus laudantium nesciunt molestiae eos consequuntur ipsa accusantium odit a, in vitae nihil, est voluptate atque natus. Natus labore in nostrum ab neque molestiae omnis iste dolor id! Provident, et.
Magni esse dolores aliquam perferendis totam hic nobis? Quae a maxime iusto quidem, est nulla numquam quibusdam repellat, odio quod voluptas accusantium. Sequi inventore harum perspiciatis maiores dolorum laboriosam. Molestias distinctio suscipit totam,
adipisci excepturi unde sunt odit sed? Adipisci ad libero molestiae recusandae quibusdam dolor dignissimos officia aut pariatur, dolore illum non numquam doloremque architecto expedita eligendi sed amet debitis est optio laborum cum! Mollitia omnis maiores
nulla ut reiciendis atque nihil, odio, cum assumenda laborum praesentium dolorem maxime sed officia. Commodi voluptatibus minima repellat aliquid mollitia tempore, cupiditate magni officiis! Aut voluptates error, hic impedit blanditiis corporis asperiores
culpa non, beatae sapiente rem. Non facere voluptatum repellendus pariatur facilis dignissimos maiores esse molestiae repudiandae reiciendis! At, dolore temporibus. Quasi aliquid assumenda, id quod quidem, eos vel porro quis ab ex hic molestias asperiores
et? Beatae autem odit mollitia dignissimos voluptas unde error tempora iure, necessitatibus blanditiis iusto adipisci vero labore nobis eligendi amet optio, facilis quae sunt reiciendis sapiente ducimus repudiandae! Aspernatur veniam alias laboriosam
ea tempora at! Recusandae maxime natus nemo pariatur modi quo reiciendis laudantium quos eligendi, consectetur eum autem dolorum laboriosam quasi inventore odio quas similique amet ex? Unde perspiciatis quos, enim, quis corrupti, aspernatur libero perferendis
dignissimos laudantium veniam exercitationem culpa itaque veritatis a delectus dolor obcaecati inventore eius! Dolorem laudantium facilis aspernatur tenetur asperiores nihil facere. Atque quam consectetur voluptas numquam? Quia aut, tenetur neque ex sequi
omnis dolores eligendi expedita voluptatem repudiandae, odio modi excepturi ea nulla, impedit asperiores tempora doloribus iure eum voluptas sed minus. Iusto sed voluptas unde, cupiditate autem perferendis consequatur. Fugiat harum dolores praesentium
modi magni hic quasi exercitationem quaerat labore, laborum inventore, minus iusto necessitatibus maxime distinctio, quae a! Omnis ab provident amet nobis similique optio aliquam minus sunt consequatur placeat facere suscipit quam officia architecto nam
veritatis debitis nesciunt, eveniet illo temporibus quos. Eius cumque a animi expedita laboriosam non quod accusantium esse vitae dolorem sed natus ducimus corrupti sequi minima perferendis soluta, mollitia alias! Exercitationem, quo. Error, amet perferendis
similique eos veniam corrupti quia accusamus nesciunt quisquam illo minima nobis natus deleniti sint alias atque fugiat sed autem et illum cum. Doloremque, reiciendis quisquam impedit natus consequuntur quod harum totam. Deserunt error deleniti tempore
ratione molestiae minus blanditiis facilis obcaecati recusandae perferendis expedita saepe voluptate aliquid eos adipisci enim, iste voluptatum, ducimus porro maiores earum. Architecto odit maiores quasi magni vel qui at cumque maxime? Qui aspernatur
dignissimos, quas soluta ipsa repudiandae reiciendis, illo praesentium rem nostrum obcaecati adipisci quos debitis dolore quaerat minus doloremque nemo dolores. Odit quasi praesentium ipsam maiores id assumenda asperiores enim, similique quod dolore aliquam
dolorem? Impedit expedita voluptas veritatis esse. Deserunt placeat consequatur molestiae iste repellat, quae quibusdam tempore corrupti repellendus asperiores impedit beatae delectus deleniti illo, vitae quo quisquam dolore aliquam voluptates, nihil
atque magni! Voluptatum cupiditate sit, dolorem debitis adipisci velit quaerat nobis? Unde qui, laudantium reprehenderit similique fugit atque, praesentium repellat ratione facere numquam harum fugiat cumque molestiae ab hic asperiores sapiente quisquam,
aliquam porro adipisci. Harum temporibus similique rem cupiditate error quis odio. Autem, dignissimos magnam consequuntur minus, at amet inventore cumque laborum in accusamus possimus officia unde quasi iusto asperiores? Ut quos facere dolorem, ullam
consectetur maxime libero odit nisi ipsa culpa eligendi odio. Animi aliquid consectetur voluptates! Nobis, beatae iste nesciunt corrupti vitae delectus architecto ratione voluptatem, veritatis, expedita voluptas. Sint, quia officia nemo reprehenderit
reiciendis mollitia consectetur. Repellat accusantium laboriosam sint cum optio voluptas hic quos tempora deleniti obcaecati rem suscipit nesciunt aperiam nisi dolor velit, vero incidunt sit facilis! Earum dignissimos inventore dolor impedit accusamus
officia reprehenderit sed minima, neque provident explicabo ab dolorem quae unde enim, obcaecati cum dolorum rerum iusto ad molestias. Quisquam ipsam odio totam, necessitatibus excepturi soluta nihil aperiam saepe minima eum cumque culpa quam in veniam
doloribus exercitationem deleniti aliquid vitae, natus dolores aut hic! Labore harum, officia repellendus repellat sit rerum. Blanditiis odit autem fuga modi culpa omnis nam earum. Enim hic veritatis inventore beatae tempora cum expedita suscipit. Earum
est quam totam, voluptatem veniam dolorem rerum qui laboriosam delectus! Praesentium distinctio rerum, vero, sint, nemo delectus vel aut quasi velit autem fugiat ad! Excepturi tenetur quam iusto quas ipsam suscipit omnis esse voluptas magnam error doloribus
quaerat quidem, nobis facere. Hic, fuga. Id aspernatur rem nulla! Illum ipsam dolores quas numquam sed ipsum optio minima cumque voluptas iure deleniti, et quisquam incidunt dicta delectus recusandae a sit architecto sunt nemo qui ratione totam dignissimos
quaerat. Minima, repudiandae odio? Veritatis nihil, accusamus vitae dignissimos nemo magni aspernatur sunt, ex minima illum, tempora a! Recusandae labore laborum cum fuga exercitationem tempora quod illum id perspiciatis quae, nisi, blanditiis mollitia
vel adipisci, fugit tenetur? Debitis eaque cum perspiciatis ad odio. Est consectetur cupiditate ratione eligendi, dolorum atque suscipit minima placeat aliquam harum magnam modi molestiae et amet repellat blanditiis officiis quo dignissimos voluptate
maxime tempore velit expedita voluptatum. Mollitia accusantium, nostrum eaque suscipit odit optio, aliquid aperiam possimus veniam tempora harum doloremque fuga excepturi consequatur magni sequi maxime deserunt. Amet aut ullam enim saepe harum! Earum,
consequuntur neque. Numquam at vero unde ea libero possimus, expedita voluptate aperiam incidunt mollitia velit, vitae voluptates ipsam sit consequuntur nisi rerum. ncidunt dicta adipisci, labore consequatur provident et recusandae ratione aliquid tempora
deserunt facilis delectus vel inventore nemo mollitia corporis aspernatur ut sunt officia quo. Excepturi adipisci magnam alias tenetur inventore, perferendis repellat placeat eos voluptate sunt laboriosam necessitatibus doloribus, odit animi, quasi facere
repudiandae magni! Error tempore quidem a modi incidunt, repellat neque. Facilis in reprehenderit sit beatae odit itaque perspiciatis nostrum praesentium perferendis quidem! Nulla optio nihil rem asperiores dolore possimus deleniti assumenda doloremque,
ipsa recusandae, officia dolorum amet quos debitis est expedita pariatur aspernatur quas eligendi! Eius voluptates in eos obcaecati, incidunt iste temporibus consectetur, doloribus tenetur illum velit delectus laborum similique inventore voluptas ab aliquam
magnam id eum odio architecto enim sed nihil fuga. Delectus at animi laborum optio modi molestias aliquid voluptatem enim, eum explicabo dolor ex dolores qui sequi, consequatur quasi impedit ratione recusandae temporibus repudiandae error, itaque accusamus.
Optio impedit aliquid quae reiciendis sunt illo molestias? Ipsum obcaecati voluptatibus, quasi doloribus vero ut pariatur aliquam consectetur. Beatae provident labore omnis rem aperiam placeat dolore eveniet adipisci ut, consectetur exercitationem et
quos dignissimos error nostrum voluptatem, non ex. Rerum distinctio inventore officiis natus quibusdam libero eius magnam veritatis vero perspiciatis! Quibusdam iure aliquid eos vel veniam? Fugit doloribus soluta maiores reprehenderit fuga? Autem facere
voluptatem at fugiat cum, non totam fuga, consectetur molestiae id beatae cupiditate, atque mollitia ullam sapiente dolor rerum. }
```

Comment: Но мне надо не прибегая к помощи JQ и Js)

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко это просто пример того что нету скролов

Comment: Второй у меня в хроме не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy  https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6n09296wu9g3qb/Video_2019-07-24_132811.wmv  видео даже снял

Comment: @Qwertiy я это везде проверял в ie11, firefox, edge, chrome

Comment: Странно, заработало. Видимо, какой-то глюк был...

Answer (score 2):

Для десктопных браузеров можно вот так:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

.outer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0 -17px -17px 0;
  height: calc(100% + 17px);
}
```

```html
<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну так айфон вроде к десктопным не относится ;) А вообще, для него есть твой вариант с `::-webkit-scrollbar`, надо только немного допилить, чтобы совместить с этим.

Comment: так это же копия моего ответа.Проста имена классов изменил и `overflow:auto` на `scroll`

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, где же копия-то? У тебя паддинг у вложенного элемента (причём 15 вместо 17, из-за чего видно скролл), который видно при добавлении выравнивания текста по двум краям, а у меня overflow: scroll и margin, которые эти проблемы устраняют.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не должно работать, проверь ещё раз. Скорее всего правые 17px текста обрезаны.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я ж специально `text-align: justify;` посавил, чтоб видно было.